# catch array with post on gatsbyjs

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a page in gatsbyjs.
and 10 posts on it.
I would like 1 to have the first kind of styling, posts from 2 to 6, the second kind of styling and the other 3 kind.

It seems to me that in order to style the appearance of posts, I need to grab an array of which these posts are iterated.

Can anyone tell me how to catch her?

[image]

I would like them to look like in the picture.
1 biggest 2 next in a smaller diva

my idea is that array [0] is the style for the largest diva for array [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUHys.jpg) and array [2] smaller box.

Is it good idea ? and how to get the number of the table thanks to which class I will be styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a single sorted array with all of your blog posts.

Create three smaller arrays with `Array.slice` with the correct amount of posts in each one.

Create three different post components, each one with its unique styling.

Create the main grid divisions in your main component with flexbox or other, and iterate over each of the three arrays, rendering one of the three post components with a unique key.